Insurance claim for NHS Emergency Treatment received by a non-resident
I visited the UK and had to use NHS emergency services whilst staying in the UK. I received a non-itemised invoice post treatment and I paid for it before leaving the UK.
Currently, I'm in the process of dealing with my insurance company and they are refusing the claim as I don't have an itemised invoice. And as far as I could find out, it is not possible to get an itemised invoice because the NHS invoice "is not a private invoice, it is a chargeable invoice".
Does anyone know anyone who successfully claimed back NHS emergency treatment costs whilst visiting the UK?
Is there anything at all I can try to do to get a different invoice with slightly more detail that my insurance company might accept? Should I call someone or some office?
Any tips and ideas would certainly be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Check the website of the NHS Trust that treated you, it may include a policy statement on itemised invoices that you could give to your insurer to prove you can’t get one. E.g. North Cumbria Integrated Care says The NHS does not provide itemised invoices; invoices are prepared in the same way as we charge the Integrated Care Board, and it is based on a Health Resource Group coding. Please do not ask for a breakdown of charges, as it is not possible – this is not a private invoice, it is a chargeable invoice

I contacted the person responsible for issuing the invoice for the hospital and they kindly sent me a letter stating that there is no itemised bill which I forwarded to the insurer along with the general sum invoice.
I also filled out a form and sent it back to the hospital to get the list of treatments done (albeit without prices) and provided that to the insurer.
The insurer also independently contacted the hospital to verify that there is no itemised bill.
In the end, the insurer approved my claim.
